# How to change pitch and tempo in AudioWorklet?

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api, audio-worklet, soundtouch

I've made the following website, you can select any song and it will hopefully play when you click play btn. I used an AudioWorklet cause I was told createScriptProcessor which I had before might've been the cause to bad audio playback on mobile phones.

Here is website: https://stevenphotos.github.io/AW/

Here is code: https://github.com/StevenPhotos/AW/tree/main

Main issue is that, I can't change the pitch or tempo. I am not used to working with AudioWorklets, I tried changing it inside the audio-processor directly before trying to use the range inputs.

Majority of the audio-processor / audio worklet was generated through AI, so I'm sorry if this is poor on my end.

I've used SoundTouch and createScriptProcessor here and it worked if you want to check it out:
https://stevenphotos.github.io/ST/

https://github.com/StevenPhotos/ST

Comment: Are you using the [SoundTouchJS audio worklet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@soundtouchjs/audio-worklet)?